Parsing shapefile from InputStream rather than from disk file using Geotools
I upload shapefile.zip from local to backend of Springboot.
Now I can write this shapefile.zip to disk firstly and unzip it.
Then to read the shapefile from disk and convert it to ShapefileDataStore like this:
    ShapefileDataStore shapefileDataStore = new ShapefileDataStore(shpfile.toURI().toURL());

But is there a method that I do not write the shapefile.zip to disk , directly convert the MultiPartFile into InputStream like this:
MultipartFile file

byte [] byteArr = file.getBytes();
log.debug("byteArr.length:"+byteArr.length);
InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArr);
ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(inputStream, Charset.forName("UTF8"));

I have realize above converting MultipartFile to ZipInputStream.
I want to improve the processing speed using a new method using memory rather than disk.
I have realize the method using WorldWind ,but WorldWind parsing shapefile is more simple than Geotools.So I want realize this method using Geotools.

Because your shapefile is really a collection of up to 13 files, it would be very hard to read one directly from a zip file. All the tools that are needed to pull out the various files exist in Java but whether you can read multiple files from a zip file (on windows?) is a mystery to me.
So you, or some one suitably incentivised could (may be) do it, but I wouldn't expect it to happen spontaneously. But the best way would be switching to a proper database.
